# Printing certain values using Collections.frequency()

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have an array as follows:

```
int[] array = {11, 14, 17, 11, 48, 33, 29, 11, 17, 22, 11, 48, 18};
```

What I wanted to do was to find the duplicate values, and print them.

So my way of doing this was to convert to `ArrayList`, then to `Set` and use a `stream` on the `Set`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    list.add(array[i]);
}

Set<Integer> dup = new HashSet<>(list);
```

I then used a `stream` to loop through it and print the values using `Collections.frequency`.

```
dup.stream().forEach((key) -> {
            System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, key));
        });
```

Which will of course print them all, even if the count is one.

I thought adding in `if(key > 1)` but it's the value I want not the key.

How can I get the value in this instance to print only where `value > 2`.

I could probably put in:

```
int check = Collections.frequency(list, key);
            if (check > 1) {
```

but this then duplicates `Collections.frequency(list, key)` in the `stream` and is quite *ugly*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you can to use `filter` to get only the values great than 2 :

```
dup.stream()
       .filter(t -> Collections.frequency(list, t) > 2)
       .forEach(key -> System.out.println(key + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, key)));
```

result in your case is :

```
11: 4
```

---

Edit

Another solution :

No need to use a `Set` or `Collections.frequency` you can just use :

```
Integer[] array = {11, 14, 17, 11, 48, 33, 29, 11, 17, 22, 11, 48, 18};
Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream().filter(t -> t.getValue() > 1)
        .forEach(key -> System.out.println(key.getKey() + ": " + key.getValue()));
```

Output

```
48: 2
17: 2
11: 4
```

Comment: I meant `>1` but I see what you mean. I take it it's not a *bad* idea then to use `Collections.frequency` twice in the same `stream`?

Comment: but here Collections.frequency(list, key) is also duplicated

Comment: it is because the OP want to print both key and value @AzzabiHaythem i try to make it more helpful i need just some time

Comment: we can also make a condition in the print without filter in these case

Answer (score 4):

The complete example without initialising `dup` in a loop and calling `Collections.frequency` for every unique element once:

```
Integer[] array = {11, 14, 17, 11, 48, 33, 29, 11, 17, 22, 11, 48, 18};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toSet())
  .stream()
  .map(v -> new SimpleEntry<>(v, Collections.frequency(list, v)))
  .filter(v -> v.getValue() > 1)
  .forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.getKey() + ":" + v.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with `Collections.frequency` is that it has to traverse all the collection to find the frequency of the given element. If you do this *for every element of the collection*, then your solution is `O(n^2)`, i.e. extremely inefficient, because the processing time increases as the square of the number of elements in the collection.

Instead, you could use a stream to create a map that counts the occurrences of each element, as follows:

```
int[] array = {11, 14, 17, 11, 48, 33, 29, 11, 17, 22, 11, 48, 18};

Map<Integer, Long> occurrences = Arrays.stream(array)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), 
        Collectors.counting()));
```

Now, if you want to only keep the values with more than 1 occurrence, you can simply remove the entries of the map whose value is equal to `1`:

```
occurrences.values().removeIf(v -> v == 1);
```

Finally, if you print the map:

```
System.out.println(occurrences);
```

You'll get the following output:

```
{48=2, 17=2, 11=4}
```

Or, to get the output in the format you expect:

```
occurrences.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": "+ v));
```

Another way, much shorter and without the overhead of streams:

```
Map<Integer, Long> occurrences = new HashMap<>();
for (int n : array) occurrences.merge(n, 1L, Long::sum);
```

Then, you remove entries for unique elements as shown before:

```
occurrences.values().removeIf(v -> v == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
int[] array = {11, 14, 17, 11, 48, 33, 29, 11, 17, 22, 11, 48, 18};

List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

// print values appearing more than once
list.stream().filter(i -> Collections.frequency(list, i) >1)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Would print:

```
48  
17  
11
```

If you also would like to get the occurences you could do something like this:

```
int[] array = {11, 14, 17, 11, 48, 33, 29, 11, 17, 22, 11, 48, 18};

List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

list.stream()
    .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(list, i) >1)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(identity(), v -> 1, Integer::sum))
    .forEach((x, y) -> System.out.println("Key: " + x +", occurence: "+ y));
```

which prints

```
Key: 48, occurence: 2
Key: 17, occurence: 2
Key: 11, occurence: 4
```

Comment: Can you add in the frequency aswell? i.e. 48 : 2, 17 : 2 etc

Comment: Sure. Updated my answer.

Comment: Nice answer! I've never seen `identity()` before. Is it `java.util.function.Function.identity;`?

Comment: Yes it is indeed. Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
package various;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Frequency {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {11, 14, 17, 11, 48, 33, 29, 11, 17, 22, 11, 48, 18};
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            list.add(array[i]);
        }

        Set<Integer> dup = new HashSet<>(list);

        dup.stream().forEach((key) -> {
            System.out.print((Collections.frequency(list, key) > 2) ? key + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, key) +"\n" : "");
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
11: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i : array) {
    if (hashmap.containsKey(i)) {
        hashmap.put(i, hashmap.get(i) + 1);
    } else {
        hashmap.put(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Stores the value and its frequency.

```
{48=2, 17=2, 33=1, 18=1, 22=1, 11=4, 29=1, 14=1}
```

EDIT: if you want to print the duplicates;

```
hashmap.entrySet().stream().filter((entry) -> ((int) entry.getValue() >= 2)).forEach((entry) -> {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
});
```

Gives you:

```
48:2
17:2
11:4
```

Answer (score 2):

To implement the desired functionality, we can facilitate Java Streams, in particular, the [`Stream.collect` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

```
<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
    BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
    BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

Please consider the following draft implementation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Input.
        final int[] inputArray = {11, 14, 17, 11, 48, 33, 29, 11, 17, 22, 11, 48, 18};

        // Processing.
        final DuplicateCounter<Integer> duplicateCounter = Arrays.stream(inputArray)
            .collect(
                DuplicateCounter<Integer>::new,
                DuplicateCounter<Integer>::accept,
                DuplicateCounter<Integer>::combine
            );

        // Output.
        System.out.println(duplicateCounter.getDuplicateCountMap());
    }

    private static final class DuplicateCounter<T> implements Consumer<T> {
        private final Map<T, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();

        public void accept(final T obj) {
            this.incrementCounter(obj, 1);
        }

        public void combine(final DuplicateCounter<T> other) {
            other.countMap.entrySet()
                .forEach(entry -> this.incrementCounter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }

        public Map<T, Integer> getDuplicateCountMap() {
            return this.countMap.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
        }

        private void incrementCounter(final T obj, int increment) {
            final Integer counter = this.countMap.getOrDefault(obj, 0);
            this.countMap.put(obj, counter + increment);
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs:

> {48=2, 17=2, 11=4}

Additional references:

1. [Reduction (The Java™ Tutorials > Collections > Aggregate Operations)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#reduce).
2. [Java 8 Streams - collect vs reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577197/).

Answer (score 2):

And yet another functional way:

```
HashMap<Integer, Long> result = Arrays.stream(array)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Function.identity(),
                    HashMap::new,
                    Collectors.counting()),
                    map -> {
                        map.entrySet().removeIf(x -> x.getValue() == 1);
                        return map;
                    }));
```

Btw the accepted answer - is probably the worst here, like every single suggestion to use `Collections.frequency` for *each* element (even if unique)

Comment: Or `map.values().removeIf(v -> v < 2)`. But it's basically just a stateful version of the second solution in the accepted answer.

Comment: @shmosel I haven't even looked below the edit there, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Filter :

```
dup.stream().filter(key -> Collections.frequency(list,key)>2).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert it to ArrayList at all. Take a look at this:

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(set.contains(array[i]))
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    else
        set.add(array[i]);
}
```