# How does reduce() method work with parallel streams in Java 8?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream, stringbuilder

I try to understand how `reduce()` method works exactly with parallel streams and I don't understand why the following code do not return the concatenation of these strings.

This is the code:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] grades = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"};

        StringBuilder concat = Arrays.stream(grades).parallel()
                .reduce(new StringBuilder(),
                        (sb, s) -> sb.append(s),
                        (sb1, sb2) -> sb1.append(sb2));

        System.out.println(concat);

    }
}
```

The code works only with sequential streams, but with parallel streams it doesn't return the concatenation. The output is different every time. Can someone explain me what's happening there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22577197/2711488  •  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction

Comment: Well the first thread to get to the reduce stage gets treated first :) if you await a sequential result, you better be using a sequential stream, or at least make it sequential before the reduce operation..

Comment: It’s different every time because “parallel” means multiple threads executing at the same time.  Running at the same time means they do not execute in order.

Comment: @VGR I understand that parallel menas multiple threads, but if instead of reduce() I'm using collect() it works perfectly even with parallel stream.

Comment: that _is_ the point - one is _mutable_ reduction and the other is _not_. you are using `reduce` like it's a mutable one, and it's not. hint: `accumulator` and `combiner` **must** return a _new_ instance of `StringBuilder`, all the time.

Answer (score 7):

The problem lies in the fact you use [`Stream::reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) for [mutable reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction). You should use [`Stream::collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) instead that can be used for safe parallel processing. You may read more about their differences in the official Oracle documentation: [Streams: Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html).

Unlike the reduce method, which always creates a new value when it processes an element, the collect method modifies or mutates an existing value.

Notice the differences in the Javadocs for the two methods:

- [`reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

  > Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using the provided identity, accumulation and combining functions.
- [`collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-):

  > Performs a mutable reduction operation on the elements of this stream.

Therefore, I suggest you do the following:

```
StringBuilder concat = Arrays.stream(grades)
    .parallel()
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append);
```