# Is there simplest possible reduce/fold method in java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Other technologies I know (.Net, JS) contain the simplest fold/reduce operation:

```
TResult reduce(TResult result, (TResult prevResult, TValue value) -> TResult)
```

One method I found requires TValue and TResult to be the same type.
Other one requires providing BinaryOperation that combines 2 TResults.
None of those constraints matches my context.
For now I ended up with code like:

```
Accumulator acc = someInitialValue;
for(Element element: list) {
    accumulator = reducer(accumulator, element);
}
```

but I believe so the basic method should be contained in stream API.

I have also taken a look for collectors, but I haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: *"I have also taken a look for collectors, but I haven't found anything helpful."* Really?!? A web search for [`java collectors`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+collectors) did not show any helpful articles? Such as [the javadoc of Collectors class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html), or [Guide to Java 8’s Collectors](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors), or [How to Use Java Stream Collectors](https://dzone.com/articles/java-stream-collectors). I find that extremely hard to believe.

Comment: for someone not aware of those, you might want to add a basic description of what actually happens in that mentioned method

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is the Java Stream framework added in Java 8.

The [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) class has 3 `reduce` methods:

- [`Optional<T> reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)
- [`T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)
- [`<U> U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

The second `reduce` method matches your example, but requires same result type. For different result type, you need to use the third `reduce` method, which requires an extra `combiner` method, since it needs to support parallel processing.

---

It also has 2 `collect` methods:

- [`<R,A> R collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)
- [`<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier, BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

The first `collect` method is the most commonly used one, when used in combination with the [`Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) factory class.

Comment: I think the question is asking whether or not there is a reduce function (or fold) that has the following signature: (a, (a, b) -> a)

Comment: Maybe you should point out the difference between `collect()` and `reduce()` or link [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22577197/9662601).

Comment: @JClassic There is, and it was already in the answer, but I've enhanced the answer to specifically point that out.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp That isn't the point of the question or the answer.

Comment: @JClassic The third method can.