# Is there a Programming Concept of Additive/Supplemental ForEach?

Tags: java, loops, paradigms, concept

My question contains 2 subquestions, therefore it is not limited to java but takes programming paradigms in general into consideration.

I need a Loop which does a usual "forEach" but also provides for each index its previous runs. Let me elaborate.

Let's define:

**OBJECTS** = a collection of **X**, where **X** is just any Type of Object/Data

**PREV** = the results of the previous iterations as a Collection of **Y**, **Y** beeing the result of a single iteration of an **X**

what "my" suplementalForEach would do is:

```
OBJECTS.supplementalForEach((PREV, OBJ) -> doStuff(PREV, OBJ))
```

or as non-stream variant

```
var PREV = new ArrayList<>();
for(var OBJ : OBJECTS) {
    var result = doStuff(PREV, OBJ);
    PREV.add(result);
}
```

So in essence in Java this would be a forEach, taking a BiFunction<R, T> instead of Consumer<T>

The Question now is, is there already a programming concept to this idea? If yes, what is it called? And if yes, is there a Java Implementation?

If no i can just implement it myself but this is a curious question of mine. Btw i didn't find anything yet on Google and Stackoverflow to this.

EDIT2:
as of now i have implemented these methods, feel free to use them as you please (Keep the comments and references)

```
/**
 * @author levent.dag
 * https://stackoverflow.com/users/9648047/levent-dag
 * 
 * naming idea with "akuzminykh"
 * https://stackoverflow.com/users/12323248/akuzminykh , 02.06.2020
 * 
 *   <pre>
 * Cumulative Iteration:
 *   the process of iterating with the results of the previous iterations
 *   
 *   definition:
 *   D domain (collection of X)
 *   X &isin; of domain, Data/Object/Value
 *   R results of previous iterations (List<Y>)
 *   
 *   f(R, X) iteration cycle/Function for current X element with the knowledge of previous iteration results R
 *     
 *   
 *   for X &isin; D {
 *     R.add(R, X)
 *   }
 *   
 *   ORDER sensible! use ordered Collections such as Lists and so on.
 *   </pre>
 * @param <X>
 * @param <Y>
 * @param col
 * @param loopIteration
 */
public static <X, Y, LIST extends List<Y>> void cumulativeIteration(final Collection<X> col, final BiFunction<List<Y>, X, Y> loopIteration, Class<Y> clazz) {
    final ArrayList<Y> previous = new ArrayList<>();
    col.forEach(x -> previous.add(loopIteration.apply(previous, x)));
}

/**
 * @author levent.dag
 * https://stackoverflow.com/users/9648047/levent-dag
 * 
 * naming idea with "akuzminykh"
 * https://stackoverflow.com/users/12323248/akuzminykh , 02.06.2020
 * 
 * Same as {@link Essentials#additiveIteration(Collection, BiFunction)}, but the previous results can be mapped.
 * 
 * @param <X>
 * @param <Y>
 * @param col
 * @param loopIteration
 * @param mapper
 */
public static <X, Y> void mappedCumulativeIteration(final Collection<X> col, final BiFunction<Map<String, Y>, X, Y> loopIteration, final Function<X, String> mapper) {
    final Map<String, Y> previous = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    col.forEach(x -> previous.put(mapper.apply(x), loopIteration.apply(previous, x)));
}
```

additionally as @daniu has pointed out you could achieve this with a collector, if you want to collect the given data.

```
col.stream().<List<Y>>collect(()->new ArrayList<>(), (pre, current) -> pre.add(loopIteration.apply(pre, current)), List::addAll);
```

Or as a standalone Collector

```
/**
 * @author levent.dag
 * https://stackoverflow.com/users/9648047/levent-dag
 * 
 * naming idea with "akuzminykh"
 * https://stackoverflow.com/users/12323248/akuzminykh , 02.06.2020
 * 
 *   <pre>
 * Cumulative Iteration:
 *   the process of iterating with the results of the previous iterations
 *   
 *   definition:
 *   D domain (collection of X)
 *   X &isin; of domain, Data/Object/Value
 *   R results of previous iterations (List<Y>)
 *   
 *   f(R, X) iteration cycle/Function for current X element with the knowledge of previous iteration results R
 *     
 *   
 *   for X &isin; D {
 *     R.add(R, X)
 *   }
 *   
 *   ORDER sensible! use ordered Collections such as Lists and so on.
 *   </pre>
 *
 * @param <OBJECT>
 * @param <RESULT>
 */
public class CumulativeListCollector<OBJECT, RESULT> implements Collector<OBJECT, List<RESULT>, List<RESULT>> {

    private final BiFunction<List<RESULT>, OBJECT, RESULT> loopIteration;

    public CumulativeListCollector(final BiFunction<List<RESULT>, OBJECT, RESULT> loopIteration) {
        this.loopIteration = loopIteration;
    }

    public static <O,R> CumulativeListCollector<O, R> of(final BiFunction<List<R>, O, R> loopIteration) {
        return new CumulativeListCollector<>(loopIteration);
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<RESULT>> supplier() {
        return ()->new ArrayList<RESULT>();
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<RESULT>, OBJECT> accumulator() {
        return (pre, current) -> pre.add(this.loopIteration.apply(pre, current));
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<RESULT>, List<RESULT>> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<RESULT>> combiner() {
        return (left, right)->{left.addAll(right); return left;};
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Set.of();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a _name_ for this?

Comment: @Sweeper yes if this concept exists

Comment: @akuzminykh yes i could do that as i've shown it in the code section, however i would like to know if this concept already exists and if so how it is called.

Comment: It doesn't seem so special or clever to me so that it's worth a special *name* ...

Comment: This reminds me of recursion in Haskell: split the list into the first element and the rest of the elements. Do something with the first element, then recursively call the function to the rest of the elements.

Comment: @akuzminykh yeah you might be right however it would be helpful to have a name for this, because how are you gonna talk about something if it has no name? Explaining a concept over and over again isn't the solution here. With that logic we also might say, why give an Object the name "Table".

Comment: @LeventDag Then, I guess, what name would you give it? Maybe you can give it a name and then it becomes established, e.g. the *"Levent-for"*. :D

Comment: @akuzminykh well in that case i would name it either "SuccessiveForEach" because each iteration is the successor and takes its predecessor into consideration.

Or SupplementingForEach but i don't know if i like that word. I'm open for naming ideas.

Comment: @LeventDag Maybe "additive iteration"? Because on each iteration you add to data that is to be used in the next iteration. Maybe something with ["Series"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)), e.g. "series iteration", as well. Anyways, I really doubt there is any already established name for it.

Comment: @akuzminykh yeah i think "additive iteration" is the most fitting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there simplest possible reduce/fold method in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384068/is-there-simplest-possible-reduce-fold-method-in-java)

Comment: @Joe no unfortunately not, A reduction does reduce a collection into a single value, which is not the aim here. 
So we dont want to accumulate our Values to a single one rather we want to loop each value with the knowledge of its predecessors results

Comment: You can easily do this using [Stream#collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) with a fitting accumulator implementation.

Comment: Actually, I think "cumulative iteration" might be the best name. This is from ["Cumulative Sum"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CumulativeSum.html) that is the sum of partial sums of a given sequence or [Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)). On each iteration you are using the cumulatively created list from the last iteration. Damn, that's some sciency stuff.

Comment: @akuzminykh yeah thats it! i was looking for the word cumulative. So "cumulative iteration"?

Comment: @daniu mhm so you would suggest a Collector like
col.stream().<List<Y>>collect(()->new ArrayList<>(), (pre, current) -> pre.add(loopIteration.apply(pre, current)), List::addAll);

I mean yeah, but in essence we are not trying to collect data but thanks for your contribution!

Comment: @LeventDag Yeah, I think that sound pretty right and seems fitting.

Comment: @akuzminykh
the Edit2 section should contain everything now