# Transform a flat list to domain objects with child objects using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have incoming objects with a flat de-normalized structure which I instantiated from a JDBC resultset. The incoming objects mirror the resultset, there's loads of repeated data so I want to convert the data into a list of parent objects with nested child collections, i.e. an object graph, or normalized list.

The incoming object's class looks like this:

```
class IncomingFlatItem {
    String clientCode;
    String clientName;
    String emailAddress;
    boolean emailHtml;
    String reportCode;
    String reportLanguage;
}
```

So the incoming data contains multiple objects for each client, which I'd like to aggregate into one client object, which contains a list of email address objects for the client, and a list of report objects.

So the Client object would look like this:

```
class Client {
    String clientCode;
    String clientName;
    Set<EmailAddress> emailAddresses;
    Set<Report> reports;
}
```

Strangely I can't find an existing answer for this. I am looking at nesting streams or chaining streams but I'd like to find the most elegant approach and I definitely want to avoid a for-loop.

Comment: why are you so definite about the for-loop approach? ;)

Comment: I don't need to ask how to do that! I want the functional approach learning experience :)

Comment: I have a similar scenario where I have another level like set of Subreports object within the Report object  so in that case how can I use the Stream API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the answerers who mentioned `Collectors.groupingBy()`. This was key to setting up a stream where I could use `reduce()`. I had erroneously believed I should be able to use `reduce` on its own to solve the problem, without `groupingBy`.

Thanks also to the suggestion to create a fluent API. I added `IncomingFlatItem.getEmailAddress()` and `IncomingFlatItem.getReport()` to fluently grab the domain objects from `IncomingFlatItem` - and also a method to convert the whole flat item to a proper domain object with its email and report nested already:

```
public Client getClient() {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.setClientCode(clientCode);
    client.setClientName(clientName);
    client.setEmailAddresses(new ArrayList());
    client.getEmailAddresses().add(this.getEmailAddress());
    client.setReports(new ArrayList<>());
    client.getReports().add(this.getReport());
    return client;
}
```

I also created business ID-based `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` methods on `Client`, `EmailAddress` and `Report` as recommended by @SamuelPhilip

Lastly for the domain objects, I created `.addReport(Report r)` and `.addEmail(EmailAddress e)` on my `Client` class, which would add the child object to `Client` if not already present. I ditched the `Set` collection type for `List` because the domain model standard is `List` and `Sets` would have meant lots of conversions to `Lists`.

So with that, the stream code and lambdas look succinct.

There are 3 steps:

1. map `IncomingFlatItems` to `Clients`
2. group the `Clients` into a map by client (relying heavily on `Client.equals()`)
3. reduce each group to one `Client`

So this is the functional algorithm:

```
List<Client> unflatten(List<IncomingFlatItem> flatItems) {
    return flatItems.parallelStream()
            .map(IncomingFlatItem::getClient)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(client -> client))
            .entrySet().parallelStream()
            .map(kvp -> kvp.getValue()
                    .stream()
                    .reduce(new Client(), 
                            (client1, client2) -> {
                                    client1.getReports()
                                            .forEach(client2::addReport);
                                    client1.getEmailAddresses()
                                            .forEach(client2::addEmail);
                                    return client2;
                    }))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I took a long time due to going off on a tangent before I really understood `reduce` - I found a solution which passed my tests while using `.stream()` but totally failed with `.parallelStream()` hence its usage here. I had to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as well otherwise it would fall over randomly with `ConcurrentModificationExceptions`

Comment: Using `Stream.reduce()` is possible the worst thing you could do, because it's violating the contract of `reduce()`. See [Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Reduction) and [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) or [Java 8 Streams - collect vs reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22577197/9662601) for more information. Use `Stream.collect()` instead.

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for the input but I think you're getting hung up on semantics. The stream reduces the flattened collection of multiple instances of each object to just one instance of the object, per group, where each group has multiple instances of an object, all having the same ID. You reference an SO question which discusses multiple different streaming issues - which one do you think is relevant?

Comment: I guess you're not visualizing the type of input data in the stream. I should have included an example so you get the right idea of what it's doing. Now that I've written a ton of tests for the stream, I've got lots of data so if I get a moment I'll paste some into the question for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is use constructor parameters and a fluent API to your advantage. Thinking "nested" flows and the stream API (with dynamic data) can get complex very quickly.

This just uses a fluent API to simplify things (you can use a proper builder pattern instead)

```
class Client {
    String clientCode;
    String clientName;
    Set<EmailAddress> emailAddresses = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Report> reports = new HashSet<>();

    public Client(String clientCode, String clientName) {
        super();
        this.clientCode = clientCode;
        this.clientName = clientName;
    }

    public Client emailAddresses(String address, boolean html) {
        this.emailAddresses = 
             Collections.singleton(new EmailAddress(address, html));
        return this;
    }

    public Client reports(String... reports) {
        this.reports = Arrays.stream(reports)
                        .map(Report::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return this;
    }

    public Client merge(Client other) {
        this.emailAddresses.addAll(other.emailAddresses);
        this.reports.addAll(other.reports);

        if (null == this.clientName)
            this.clientName = other.clientName;
        if (null == this.clientCode)
            this.clientCode = other.clientCode;

        return this;
    }
}

class EmailAddress {
    public EmailAddress(String e, boolean html) {

    }
}

class Report {
    public Report(String r) {

    }
}
```

And...

```
Collection<Client> clients = incomingFlatItemsCollection.stream()
        .map(flatItem -> new Client(flatItem.clientCode, flatItem.clientName)
                          .emailAddresses(flatItem.emailAddress, flatItem.emailHtml)
                          .reports(flatItem.reportCode, flatItem.reportLanguage))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Client::getClientCode,
                Collectors.reducing(new Client(null, null), Client::merge)))
        .values();
```

Or you can also just use mapping functions that convert `IncomingFlatItem` objects to `Client`.

Comment: But this doesn't get rid of duplicate clients, does it? Duplicate client objects will appear when a client has multiple emails, or reports, each with only one object in its email or report collection. I have a bad feeling we are not talking about the same object structure. I updated the question.

Comment: Ah... Now I see. Sorry I missed the fact. Will update now.

Comment: @Adam I've made an edit. This should remove duplicates (by clientCode)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something on the lines of using mapping function to convert `List<IncomingFlatItem>` to `Set<Reports/EmailAddress>` as:

```
Function<List<IncomingFlatItem>, Set<EmailAddress>> inferEmailAddress =
        incomingFlatItems -> incomingFlatItems.stream()
                .map(obj -> new EmailAddress(obj.getEmailAddress(), 
                                             obj.isEmailHtml()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Function<List<IncomingFlatItem>, Set<Report>> inferReports =
        incomingFlatItems -> incomingFlatItems.stream()
                .map(obj -> new Report(obj.getReportCode(), 
                                       obj.getReportLanguage()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

and further using `groupingBy` and mapping the entries to `List<Client>` as:

```
List<Client> transformIntoGroupedNormalisedContent(
                  List<IncomingFlatItem> incomingFlatItemList) {
    return incomingFlatItemList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(inc ->
                    Arrays.asList(inc.getClientCode(), inc.getClientName())))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> new Client(e.getKey().get(0), 
                                 e.getKey().get(1),
                                 inferEmailAddress.apply(e.getValue()), 
                                 inferReports.apply(e.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Or possibly `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(inc.getClientCode(), inc.getClientName())` in grouping to avoid accessing elements with hardcoded index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
List<Client> clients = items.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> Arrays.asList(i.getClientCode(), i.getClientName())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> new Client(e.getKey().get(0), e.getKey().get(1),
                e.getValue().stream().map(i -> new EmailAddress(i.getEmailAddress(), i.isEmailHtml())).collect(Collectors.toSet()),
                e.getValue().stream().map(i -> new Report(i.getReportCode(), i.getReportLanguage())).collect(Collectors.toSet())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

At the beginning you group your items by `clientCode` and `clientName`. After that you map the results to your `Client` object.

Make sure the `.equals()` and `hashCode()` methods are implemented for `EmailAddress` and `Report` to ensure they are distinct in the set.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to iterate over entry sets (don't want to handle `Map.Entry`) or prefer a different solution without `groupingBy`, you can also use `toMap` with a merge function to aggregate your values. This approach works nicely  because `Client` can hold the initial single item and the accumulated collection of all `EmailAddress` (Note: I used a utility function `com.google.common.collectSets.union` for conciseness, but you can just work with e.g. HashSet).

The following code demonstrates how to do it (add Reports in the same manner as EmailAddress, and add the other fields you want). I left the merge function inline and did not add an AllArgsConstructor, but feel free to refactor.

```
static Client mapFlatItemToClient(final IncomingFlatItem item) {
    final Client client = new Client();
    client.clientCode = item.clientCode;
    client.emailAddresses = Collections.singleton(mapFlatItemToEmail(item));
    return client;
}

static EmailAddress mapFlatItemToEmail(final IncomingFlatItem item) {
    final EmailAddress address = new EmailAddress();
    address.emailAddress = item.emailAddress;
    return address;
}

public static void example() {
    final List<IncomingFlatItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    // Aggregated Client Info by Client Code
    final Map<String, Client> intermediateResult = items.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.<IncomingFlatItem, String, Client> toMap(
                            flat -> flat.clientCode,
                            flat -> mapFlatItemToClient(flat),
                            (lhs, rhs) -> {
                                final Client client = new Client();
                                client.clientCode = lhs.clientCode;
                                client.emailAddresses = Sets.union(lhs.emailAddresses, rhs.emailAddresses);
                                return client;
                            }));

    final Collection<Client> aggregatedValues = intermediateResult.values();
}
```